# How to embed a YouTube video inside a page content in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: publishing-page, html-editor

I have a SharePoint 2010 publishing site. I need to embed YouTube videos inside the page content of some pages. After inserting the HTML in the HTML Edit mode, I find that SharePoint removed the YouTube code from the HTML source.

Is there a way to get around this problem?

Comment: How does your code look like? Please give of some input :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint likes to keep code safe and when adding embedded code, therefore it removes the Youtube embedded code from the Page.  Hopefully, [this link](http://www.bfcnetworks.com/embed-youtube-and-other-code-into-sharepoint-2010/) will help you getting across the problem

Comment: haha that was the same ressource I thought about :D

Answer (score 0):

[This post](http://www.sharepointkings.com/2010/01/how-to-embed-video-in-sharepoint.html) gives an explanation on how to embed YouTube videos inside the page content with [Content Editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.contenteditorwebpart.aspx) web part using `embed` tag

```
<embed src="http://link to video goes here"
      autoplay="true"
      loop="false"
      width="200"
      height="200">
</embed>
```

---

Also, I recommend to take a look on the different approach as described [here](http://vgrem.wordpress.com/2012/10/28/embedding-and-sharing-video-in-sharepoint/) and [here](http://vgrem.wordpress.com/2012/11/23/embedding-and-sharing-video-in-sharepoint-part-two-posting-embedded-code-support-for-different-video-providers-preview-view/)

**The main idea to store embed code in Custom List and not in Page Content**
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do this on SharePoint 2013, there's an "Embed Code" option in the Ribbon. To add a Youtube video, go to Youtube and view the "Share this video" and click on "Embed" which will give you the iframe code to add to the SharePoint snippet. It would look something like this

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/nJjXnTcP1hc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

For 2010 use an HTML Form web part. Add it, edit the web part, click on the Source Editor button, delete the sample form code and paste in your embed code.

The other way to do it on 2010, is to paste your code into a text file, upload the text file to your site, add a content editor web part, edit the web part and then paste the link to your text file into the Content Link box.